# JQuery Mobile testing a data- attribute for boolean value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a list of li tags in an unordered list and each li has an attribute called `data-clicked=false`. this if... else if... statement will test to see if `data-clicked==true/false` and then give an alert with the value of the attribute. The problem is that this is always alerting "true" when it should be "false" since by default at the start they are all set to false.

```
$("ul").click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).data("clicked"==true)) {
        alert("true")
    }
    else if ($(event.target).data("clicked"==false)) {
        alert("false")
    }
});
```

basically all I want to know is how I can test to see if the `data-clicked` attribute is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition

```
 if ($(event.target).data("clicked"==true)) {
```

wont work. It should be

```
if ($(event.target).data("clicked")==true) {
```

and same would be the case for the `else if` part

Comment: @chrispytoes, if this worked, then you are supposed to accept this answer.